# Is there any inbuilt method in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a string and i need to check whether the string is equal or not?
Is there any inbuilt method in jquery ?

### What i need :

1.I need to check the string using the jquery method .
2.Is there any inbuilt method to validate the string comparision in Jquery ?

Comment: do you have something else in mind or its just plain string comparion///

Comment: You do not need a chunky library to replicate the functionality of one of the oldest operators in the language itself!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need jquery?   The comparison (String1 == String2) should suffice?

Comment: You're correct, but I'm wondering if maybe he isn't talking about using jQuery to obtain the values... something like `$( '#input1' ).val() == $( '#input2' ).val()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about the types of the operands then you can use strict equal to operator

```
string str = "100";
string str1 = 100;

str === str1 will return false(since the operands are not of the same type)
str == str1 will return true
```

See [**comparison operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: why to make so complicated for a simple string compare